# How to open a database already populated with ionic 3 and sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ionic-native, ionic3

I need to use a ready sqlite bank that I already have and open it within my project. In the documentation the 'location' of sqlite is always set to: default, so I'm not sure where to save my .sqlite file, or how to open that database, 'openDatabase' no longer works with the ionic update, and create is not opening, but creating a new database, does anyone know how to solve it? Anything helps, thanks!
I am using ionic 3 and sqlite 3 and these are the information from my ionic project:

> Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
>
> Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.0
>
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
>
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
>
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
>
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
>
> ios-sim version: Not installed
>
> OS: Windows 10
>
> Node Version: v7.2.1
>
> Xcode version: Not installed

And this is my code:

```
loading() {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            this.sqlite.create({
                name: 'database_name.sqlite',
                location: 'default'
            })
                .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

                    db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table_name', {})
                        .then((data) => {
                            console.log('Executed SQL data: ', data)
                        }).catch(e => console.log(e, "Error in select"));
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e, "Error opening database"));
        })
    }
```

Comment: have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this:

```
const options: any = {
                                name: 'indicedb.db',
                                location: 'default',
                                createFromLocation: 1
                            };

                            this.sqlite.create(options).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {


               db.executeSql(`SELECT * FROM table;`, []).then((data) => {
                                console.log("success", data);
                            }, (e) => {
                                console.log("error SELECT", e);
                            });
                            }).catch(e => {
                                console.log("error open db", e);
                            });
```